# Application crashing with WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager, androidx

So recently I'm trying to test WorkManager and I'm having a bug which I don't know how to solve it...

The error that I'm having is this one :

```
2018-06-16 16:36:36.594 23798-23815/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
Process: com.example.damiii.myjobintentservice, PID: 23798
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:135)
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:116)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:150)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:409)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:97)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:55)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:253)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.EnqueueRunnable.addToDatabase(EnqueueRunnable.java:93)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.EnqueueRunnable.run(EnqueueRunnable.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I checked where I could have this error and it's seems that when I'm putting comments to that code :

```
        //WorkRequest can be customised for backoff criteria
    OneTimeWorkRequest checkOfflineNetworkState = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NoNetworkWorker.class).setConstraints(mConstraints).build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(checkOfflineNetworkState);
```

My application works nicely...
I don't know if the problem is from `WorkManager` or the implementation that I did...

This is the informations of my project :

`minSDKversion : 14`

`targetSDKversion : 28`

My `gradle.build` :

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
//    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha3'
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha02"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
}
```

Anyone to help me ?
THank you :)

P.S.: This is the code from `NoNetworkWorker` :

```
package com.example.damiii.myjobintentservice;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.work.Worker;

public class NoNetworkWorker extends Worker {


/**
 * Override this method to do your actual background processing.
 *
 * @return The result of the work, corresponding to a {@link WorkerResult} value.  If a
 * different value is returned, the result shall be defaulted to
 * {@link WorkerResult#FAILURE}.
 */
@Override
public WorkerResult doWork() {

    Log.d("Hello", "I'm offline :D");

    return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
}
}
```

Comment: Same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896393/room-crashes-while-accessing-it-store-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue will fixed with the next AndroidX version of Room.

Source : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110100403

Comment: <3 Thanks BenjaminBihr !

Answer (score 2):

update to WorkManager version 1.0.0-alpha03

Comment: I am using 1.0.0-alpha04 but still getting the crash

Comment: Same with version `2.6.0`.